# Iframe with footer and scrollabe content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have aspx page that are in `iframe`.

I need to add buttons on this page to footer and make it's content scrollable (all content is inside `table`).

[image]

So on page I have :

```css
/* Buttons Footer*/
.full-scrollable-height {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

form.form-full-height {
 height: 83%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
}

 form.form-full-height .footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*padding-top: 15px;*/
  /*border-top: 1px solid #B7B7B7;*/
 }
/* End Footer*/

td{height:30px;border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="height:200px">
<form class="form-full-height">
  <div class="full-scrollable-height">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="pull-left">
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Save Template</a>
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Load Template</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</form>
</div>
```

Problems : Is this approach fine? I mean setting height for table-wrap div? Can I somehow skip this is I know height of iframe?

And can I set buttons in the middle of footer (vertical-align : middle doesn't work here and if make footer `inline-block` it looks very bad )

Comment: So where is the iframe?

Comment: @Midas, All my form is inside iframe. I thought it in unnecessary to add `iframe` to code.

Comment: *Can I somehow skip this is I know height of iframe?* - Can you clarify this?

Comment: @Midas I set height of table wrapper. I don't wan't do to it. So I ask if there is some solution to avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few possible ways to achieve scrollable content with a fixed footer.

Here are 3 possible solutions.

**Method 1: Using flexbox**

```css
html, body, form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.full-scrollable-height {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
footer .container {
  padding: 15px 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-full-height">
  <div class="full-scrollable-height">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Save Template</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Load Template</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</form>
```

**Method 2: Using absolute positioning + Javascript**

```js
window.onload = function() { // Better is to use the DOM ready event here
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var content = form.getElementsByClassName('full-scrollable-height')[0];
  var footer = form.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];

  footer.style.position = 'absolute';
  footer.style.bottom = 0;

  (window.onresize = function() {
    var height = form.offsetHeight - footer.offsetHeight;
    content.style.height = height + 'px';
  })();
};
```

```css
html, body, form {
  height: 100%;
}
.full-scrollable-height {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
table, footer {
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  border-top: 1px solid silver
}
footer .container {
  padding: 15px 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-full-height">
  <div class="full-scrollable-height">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Save Template</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Load Template</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</form>
```

**Method 3: Using fixed position on the footer**

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
footer .container {
  padding: 15px 0
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-top: 1px solid silver
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-full-height">
  <div class="full-scrollable-height">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Save Template</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Load Template</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codes,for checking purpose the codes in inline.Please try this.

```
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
}
form.form-full-height .footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**HTML with inline css:**

```
  <footer class="footer">
          <div class="container" style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="clear: both ! important; vertical-align: middle ! important; height: 100%; display: table;">

  <div class="" style="display: table-cell; margin: auto ! important; vertical-align: middle ! important; height: 100% ! important;">
         <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Save Template</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Load Template</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Save</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```